# get value from html

Tags: c#, html, nullreferenceexception

I'm fairly new to C#, and I'm trying to get a level from an in-browser game. This is the code I used and it came with an error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

```
HtmlElementCollection elmnt = webBrowser1.Document
                                         .GetElementById("levelFrontTopArea")
                                         .GetElementsByTagName("value");
levellabel.Text = elmnt[0].InnerText;
```

Below I will show you the HTML code:

```
<div class="levelFrontTopArea">
   <a style="text-decoration:none" href="/profile.php">7</a>
</div>
```

Comment: While he is getting a `NullReference` exception, its only because he is trying to get a class element that doesnt have an id.  The question is actually about how to get a class element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get an element by class you can loop through the div tags.

```
static IEnumerable<HtmlElement> ElementsByClass(HtmlDocument doc, string className)
{
  foreach (HtmlElement e in doc.All)
    if (e.GetAttribute("className") == className)
      yield return e;
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
var elmnt = ElementsByClass(webBrowser1.Document, "levelFrontTopArea");
levellabel.Text = elmnt.FirstOrDefault().InnerText;
```

Comment: Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement>

Comment: Oops, just copied your code on that, you can get the first element by using `FirstOrDefault`  Because the method returns an IEnumerable, you can use it in a foreach as well.

Answer (score 0):

You're using GetElementByID, but your div has no ID.  Try changing your HTML to:

```
<div ID="levelFrontTopArea" class="levelFrontTopArea">
  <a style="text-decoration:none" href="/profile.php">7</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I cant change the code from the source If its just reading it, Right?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  Did you write the html yourself?  Or is it generated by something?

Comment: Well then my solution won't work unless you're able to change the code that generates the html so that it gives it an ID.  You could use getElementsByClassName.

Comment: There is only GetElementByTagName

Comment: OK.  I think you need to change what you put in GetElementsByTagName too.  Make it GetElementsByTagName("a")

Comment: Do I need to add a Using System.?

Comment: I have never seen a GetElementsByClassName method in c#.  You can [write one](http://robertnyman.com/2008/05/27/the-ultimate-getelementsbyclassname-anno-2008/) however.

Comment: Yeah, there isn't one, I was thinking of javascript.  You should use @paqogomez 's answer.

Comment: I get the error Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Windows.Forms.HtmlElement> with the code and the call..